# .net core asp-route-id tag helper with multivariable id

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am using the tag helper normaly like this:
`<a asp-action="ActionName" asp-route-id="@item.id" class="btn btn-sm btn-info mt-2">Edit</a>`

or `<button asp-action="ActionName" asp-route-id="@item.id class="btn btn-sm btn-info mt-2""></button>`

However, when I try to use the tag helper with a composite primary key I am unable to get the link right.

`asp-route-id="@item.ID1, @item.ID2"` = ActionName`/Id1,Id2`

`asp-route-id="@item.ID1?ID2=@item.ID2"` = ActionName`/Id1%3FID2%3DId2?`

How can I use the `asp-route-id` and have it putput `/Id1?ID2=Id2` or `/Id1?{SpecifiedName}=Id2`?

I found a workarout for `anchor` using `Html.ActionLink`, but not for `button`

Comment: How about this?: `asp-route-id="@item.ID1" asp-route-SpecifiedName="@item.ID2"`

Comment: Solved my question! Though, I am unable to pass anything but the `asp-route-id` when submitting a form with the button. (the `formaction` link is what it should be, but only the `asp-route-id` value is passed)

Comment: @Sondre You can have another parameter in the action to accept ID2 like this:`public IActionResult Test(string id, string SpecifiedName)`

Comment: This does indeed work with anchor tags, but not with the button, as I am passing the form values using it. I end up only passing the `asp-rout-id` value and nothing more

Comment: Hi @Sondre Can you show us your form codes, the controller action as well? since it can work on my side, you can see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working demo.

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />

    <button asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="1" asp-route-id2="2" class=" btn btn-info ">Edit</button>
</form>
```

View:

[image]

After submit the button, the generate url:

```
https://localhost:5001/Home/Index/1?id2=2
```

The request payload:

[image]

Controller action:

[image]